# 14.04 -> 14.10 not shown in software updater

Tags: updates, update-manager, 14.10

I'm trying to upgrade my 14.04 system to 14.10.  Following standard instructions for doing so do not produce expected results on my system.

When I run "sudo apt-get upgrade update-manager-core", the message is "update-manager-core is already the newest version."  When I run the "Software Updater" GUI tool, it does not offer an option upgrade to the new release.  When I choose System Menu / About This Computer, the button in the lower right of the window is disabled and labelled "System Up-To-Date", after it initially indicates that the application is checking for update.

Release 14.10 was scheduled for release on 23 October, four days ago, and other users have confirmed that they were able upgrade by the end of that day.  Can someone please help me determine why I am not able to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 is an LTS (**L**ong-**t**erm **s**upported) version so it will by default not ask you to upgrade to non-LTS versions like 14.10.

If you launch `Software & Updates` from Dash and then go to the `Updates` tab, at the bottom you can choose Ubuntu to notify you about new non-LTS versions as well ("For any new version"). Just choose this and run update-manager again and it should detect 14.10.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: works for me, at least :) thx